Issue accessing variable in Yaml pipeline
I have a yaml pipeline with 2 stages, each one job and multiple steps.
I based my approach on what is documented on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage
stages:
- stage: ExportSolutionStage
  displayName: 'Export solution to git'
  jobs:
  - template: ../Templates/Jobs/export-solution-job.yml
    parameters:
      SolutionName: ${{parameters.Solution}}  
      ServiceConnectionName: ${{variables.serviceConnectionName}}
      Repo: 'VAB.PowerPlatform.ReleaseSolutions'
      GitUserName: ${{parameters.GitUserName}}
      GitUserEmail: ${{parameters.GitUserEmail}}
      Branch: $(branch)
      PublishCustomizations: ${{parameters.PublishCustomizations}}

- stage: build_stage
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  dependsOn : ExportSolutionStage
  jobs:
  - template: ../Templates/Jobs/build-release-solution-job.yml
    parameters:
      SolutionName: ${{parameters.Solution}}      
      Branch: $(branch)

The underlying template for the job in the first stage is this
jobs:

- deployment: ExportSolutionJob
  timeoutInMinutes: 360
  displayName: 'Export solution'
  environment: ${{parameters.ServiceConnectionName}}

  pool: 
    name: 'Azure Pipelines'
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:

          # Checkout Pipelines
          - template: ../Steps/checkout-pipelines.yml

          - checkout: ${{ parameters.Repo }}
            displayName: 'Checkout Target Branch'

          - template: ../Steps/install-tools.yml

          - template: ../Base/export-solution-base.yml
            parameters:
              SolutionName: ${{parameters.SolutionName}}  
              ServiceConnectionName: ${{parameters.ServiceConnectionName}}
              Repo: ${{parameters.Repo}}
              GitUserName: ${{parameters.GitUserName}}
              GitUserEmail: ${{parameters.GitUserEmail}}
              Branch: ${{parameters.Branch}}
              PublishCustomizations: ${{parameters.PublishCustomizations}}

Included in one of the step templates is this template
# Set Version
  - template:   ../Steps/set-version.yml
    parameters:
      SolutionName: ${{ parameters.SolutionName }}

Which contains this step
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Get Solution Version and Set as Build'
    name: SolutionVersion
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        
        Write-Host "Fetch current solution version for solution ${{parameters.SolutionName}}"
        ... obscured logic
        $newVersion = $versionToday + $newVersion

        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewVersion;isOutput=true]$newVersion"        

In the job of the second stage, I try to get that NewVersion variable via this part
variables:
    NewVersion: $[stageDependencies.ExportSolutionStage.ExportSolutionJob.outputs['SolutionVersion.NewVersion']]

However when I run the pipeline, it cannot resolve this variable.
Variables:
  NewVersion:
    Parsing expression: <stageDependencies.ExportSolutionStage.ExportSolutionJob.outputs['SolutionVersion.NewVersion']>
    Evaluating: stageDependencies['ExportSolutionStage']['ExportSolutionJob']['outputs']['SolutionVersion.NewVersion']
    Expanded: Null
    Result: ''

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Regards,
Sven

Based on your YAML sample, you are defining the variable in the deployment job and set runOnce strategy.
In this case, when you use the cross stage variables, you need to follow the following format:
$[stageDependencies.{stagename}.{jobname}.outputs['{jobname}.{stepname}.variablename']]

Here is an example:
variables:
  NewVersion: $[stageDependencies.ExportSolutionStage.ExportSolutionJob.outputs['ExportSolutionJob.SolutionVersion.NewVersion']]

Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Support for output variables
